# How to intercept and modify bulk updates?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, entity-framework-plus, entity-framework-extensions

In several places in my code I am doing bulk updates using the handy dandy `Z.EntityFramework.Plus` extensions, e.g.

```
await db.Foos
        .Where(f => f.SomeCondition)
        .UpdateAsync(f => new Foo { Field1 = "bar", Field2 = f.Field2 + 1 });
```

which will update all `Foo` records where `SomeCondition` is true, setting `Field1` to "bar" and `Field2` will be incremented by one.

Now a new requirement has come up, where some tables (but not all) are tracking `ModifiedDate`. That includes records where I'm doing bulk updates.

So my approach is like this. I have an interface:

```
public interface ITrackModifiedDate
{
    DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

So all my classes that track `ModifiedDate` can implement `ITrackModifiedDate`. Then, I write a middle-man extension to intercept the `.UpdateAsync()` calls:

```
public static async Task<int> UpdateAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, T>> updateFactory)
        where T : class
{
    if (typeof(ITrackModifiedDate).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        // TODO Now what?
    }

    return await BatchUpdateExtensions.UpdateAsync(queryable, updateFactory);
}
```

As you can see, I'm not entirely sure how to modify `updateFactory` to set `ModifiedDate` to `DateTime.UtcNow`, on top of whatever other fields are already being updated.

How to do it?

**UPDATE:** I'm not averse to changing my extension so that it only accepts `T` of type `ITrackModifiedDate`, if that helps, i.e.

```
public static async Task<int> UpdateAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, T>> updateFactory)
    where T : class, ITrackModifiedDate
{
        // TODO what now?

    return await BatchUpdateExtensions.UpdateAsync(queryable, updateFactory);
}
```

Comment: I didn't use `Z.EntityFramework.Plus` but what is inside of `Expression<Func<T, T>> updateFactory`? is it list of properties that needs to be updated?

Comment: Most likely `updateFactory` will have list of properties to update and you can make own `ExpressionVisitor` that will process the whole expression tree and then when it finds Body node, it will add additional set statement

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov exactly right: you supply a new `T` with properties set to the values you want updated.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov If you can help me with that `ExpressionVisitor`, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with following code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; 

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new SomeContext())
        {
            await context
                .Customers
                .Where(c => c.Email.Contains("42"))
                .CustomUpdateAsync((c) => new Customer()
                {
                    Email = "4242"
                });
        }
    }

}

public static class Helper
{
    public static async Task<int> CustomUpdateAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, T>> updateFactory)
        where T : class
    {
        var targetType = typeof(T);
        if (typeof(ITrackModifiedDate).IsAssignableFrom(targetType))
        {
            updateFactory = (Expression<Func<T, T>>)new TrackModifiedDateVisitor().Modify(updateFactory);
        }

        return await BatchUpdateExtensions.UpdateAsync(queryable, updateFactory);
    }
}


public class TrackModifiedDateVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Expression Modify(Expression expression)
    {
        return Visit(expression);
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node is MemberInitExpression initExpression)
        {
            var existingBindings = initExpression.Bindings.ToList();
            var modifiedProperty = initExpression.NewExpression.Type.GetProperty(nameof(ITrackModifiedDate.ModifiedDate));

            // it will be `some.ModifiedDate = currentDate`
            var modifiedExpression = Expression.Bind(
                modifiedProperty,
                Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now, typeof(DateTime))
                );

            existingBindings.Add(modifiedExpression);

            // and then we just generate new MemberInit expression but with additional property assigment
            return base.Visit(Expression.MemberInit(initExpression.NewExpression, existingBindings));
        }

        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}


public class SomeContext: DbContext
{
    public SomeContext()
        : base("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SomeContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class Customer: ITrackModifiedDate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}

public interface ITrackModifiedDate
{
    DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Needed part is `TrackModifiedDateVisitor` class that traverse through `updateFactory` expression and when it finds `MemberInitExpression` and updates it. Initially it has list of property assigments, and we generate a new one for `ModifiedDate` and create new `MemberInitExpression` with existing assigments plus generated one.

As result after visitor code is executed - `updateFactory` would have

```
c => new Customer() {Email = "4242", ModifiedDate = 5/16/2019 23:19:00}
```